# how to update mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to update an int. in my MySQL Database with php. The int. comes from some Javascript. Here is my code where I get the int.:

```
<form action="SCD.php" method="POST">
<span name="Int_1" id="Int_`1">0</span><br>
<button type="button" onclick="UpdateData()">Update</button>
Name: <input type="Text" name="Name"></input>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Data">
</form>
```

The javascript pasts the int. in the span element when you click on the Updat button. That works perfectly.

Now I want to update this in the database. Here is my code:

```
<?php

$Int_1= $_POST['Int_1'];
$Name = $_POST['Name'];

if($Name) {
include_once("Includes/Database_conx.php");

$query_name = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='$Name'")
or die(mysql_error());
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query_name);

if($numrows != 0) {
    //User exists
    $query_int("UPDATE Users SET Int='$Int_1' WHERE Username='$Name'")
    or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Data updated";
} else {
    echo "THat user does not exist";
}
} else {
echo "Please fill in a name";
}

?>
```

I get a error on line 15 in the php document. Line 15:

```
$query_int("UPDATE Users SET Int='$Int_1' WHERE Username='$Name'")
```

what is wrong with it? (Sorry if I missed anything, this is my first question on Stack Overflow)

Comment: It might help to see your connection code (just blank out the user/password/etc), but I should also mention that you are not checking/cleaning POST inputs and using an outdated db library (`mysql_*` is deprecated - you should be using MySQLi or PDO)

Comment: where is $query_int function in your code. If no such function is exists than write `mysql_query("UPDATE Users SET Int=".$Int_1."  WHERE Username='".$Name."'")`

Answer (score 2):

`$query_int` is undefined variable, not function name so you can use it like that.
You probably wanted to use `mysql_query()` here, but it's also not good. Use `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span name="Int_1" id="Int_1">0</span>
```

span cannot be send to the server.

you can try input element instead.

Comment: What element should I use instead. I want it that the number in the element can be changed with Javascript. Can you write an example if possible?

Answer (score 0):

`INT` is a reserved word in MySQL, so you should use backticks if you have a column with such name. Your query to the server should be

```
UPDATE Users SET `Int`='$Int_1' WHERE Username='$Name'
```